# How can be printer available on Kubuntu

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, printing, software-installation

I am using Kubuntu. I want to connect my `brother DCP 6690cw` printer.
But no printer driver listed to add my printer. How do I connect to printer to Kubuntu?
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

i am from denmark not so got to englisk....go to
http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp6690cw_eu_as&os=128
use the driver Driver >>Install Tool<< download 
open the terminal  GO TO SAME PLACE THE >>Install Tool<< AM IN and in terminal write 
     ..                 Bash linux-brprinter-installer-* * * - * DCP 6690cw
or
     ..               Bash linux-brprinter-installer-* * * - * 6690cw 
and the printer will install

Comment: English speaking or not, this is correct  +1 and welcome